# Get text from class that has multiple elements

Tags: xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm a little new to Scrapy. I'm trying to get the text from the following element:

```
<h1 class="entry-title single-title typesquare_option" itemprop="headline" rel="bookmark">Target Text Here</h1>
```

But I don't know how to tell scrapy "Get the text from H1 but skip the itemprop and rel elements". I can get the H1 element this way:

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"entry-title")]')
```

which returns

```
[<Selector xpath='//*[contains(@class,"entry-title")]' data='<h1 class="entry-title single-title" ...'>]
```

so I'm getting close, but if I try to get the text the scrapy shell aborts. How do I get the text? Most of the examples I've seen for classes have the text right next to the class name, like:

```
<h1 class="easy-text">This text is easy to get.</h1>
```

But this one has two more things before the text, itemprop="headline" rel="bookmark" and I can't write the correct Xpath to get to the text. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tensigh, at first, thanks to give a chance to explain on it. From the html DOM, you will notice that the  `class, itemprop, rel` aren't direct child nodes of `h1`. They are called attribute nodes and immediate after node of these  attribute nodes are generally text nodes that's why whenever we  want to grab attribute's value, then we get its  immediate after text node as value. Here the `Target Text Here` is direct child/ immediate after text node of h1. As `Target Text Here` is direct child node of h1, so we can simply grab it as follows: `response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()`

Please see the output/implementation in `scrapy shell`:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
```

#I prettyfied your html tree using BeautifulSoup before paste it on scrapy shell for a bit better understanding.

```
In [4]: %paste

html_doc="""
<h1 class="entry-title single-title typesquare_option" itemprop="headline" rel="bookmark">
 Target Text Here
</h1>

"""

## -- End pasted text --

In [5]: sel = Selector(text=html_doc)

In [6]: sel.getall()
Out[6]: ['<html><body><h1 class="entry-title single-title typesquare_option" itemprop="headline" rel="bookmark">\n Target Text Here\n</h1></body></html>']

In [7]: p = sel.xpath('//h1/text()').get()

In [8]: p
Out[8]: '\n Target Text Here\n'

In [9]: p = sel.xpath('//h1/text()').get().strip()

In [10]: p
Out[10]: 'Target Text Here'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured they weren't child nodes but I didn't know what to call them, and I appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Thank  you too  a lot. You've asked a great question and it's one of  the best answers of my tags list

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer but if someone can explain why it worked I'd be grateful. This is what did the trick:

```
response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"entry-title single-title")]/text()').get()
```

Don't know why it didn't work before, it could have been locale settings (the text isn't in English).